# How can I force TileCache to NOT render missing tiles (read only mode)?

Tags: python, mapserver, tilecache

I have a working disk TileCache that I do not want additional images to be rendered and saved to disk. Is it possible to force TileCache to a "read-only" mode? At the moment, I have set the folder permissions of the disk cache to read only as a temporary solution. This is the error I receive:

```
An error occurred: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/tilecache/wms_layer1/07/000/000/037'
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/TileCache/Service.py", line 256, in modPythonHandler
    apacheReq.method,
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/TileCache/Service.py", line 208, in dispatchRequest
    return self.renderTile(tile, params.has_key('FORCE'))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/TileCache/Service.py", line 139, in renderTile
    if (data): image = self.cache.set(tile, data)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/TileCache/Caches/Disk.py", line 79, in set
    self.makedirs(dirname)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/TileCache/Caches/Disk.py", line 33, in makedirs
    raise E
```

I am hoping that there is a way to hack TileCache to quietly ignore missed hits on the existing disk cache, so as not to attempt to render those missing tiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking to implement a read only tilecache, I would highly recomend switching to the modern equivalent to TileCache: TileStache

http://tilestache.org/

This solved all of my problems and I got to abondoned an ancient system. :)